# html td table search

Tags: javascript, html

The question is how to perform a search in the certain column of the table

I use the following js script and the input tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSearch() {
        var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
        var targetTable = document.getElementById('dataTable');
        var targetTableColCount;

        //Loop through table rows
        for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
            var rowData = '';

            //Get column count from header row
            if (rowIndex == 0) {
                targetTableColCount = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.length;
                continue; //do not execute further code for header row.
            }

            //Process data rows. (rowIndex >= 1)
            for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < targetTableColCount; colIndex++) {
                var cellText = '';

                if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
                    cellText = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).innerText;
                else
                    cellText = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).textContent;

                rowData += cellText;
            }

            // Make search case insensitive.
            rowData = rowData.toLowerCase();
            searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

            //If search term is not found in row data
            //then hide the row, else show
            if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) == -1)
                targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none';
            else
                targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row';
        }
    }
</script>
```

And i want to modify this script to search only in the desired column

Comment: Provide the table html code. What do you mean by "certain column". A predetermined one? Or the user can choose the column?

Comment: i want to make several inputs to search across the certain predetermined column for each one, because the table is quite big and using only one search input would make results excessive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < targetTableColCount; colIndex++) {
```

To instead use a specific column number:

```
if(colIndex<targetTableColCount) //Ensures the selected column exists
```

To get the colIndex number, you could make a dropdown with the column name as the text and the index as the value.

```
<option id="searchID" onchange="UpdateColIndex()">
<select value="0">Column 1</select>
<select value="1">Column 2</select>
</option>
<script>
var colIndex=0;
function UpdateColIndex()
{
    colIndex = document.getElementById("searchID").value;
}
</script>
```